# Snoop program window is just a line?

Tags: snoop

I opened up Snoop today so I could inspect some properties of my WPF program's window.  And the Snoop "bar" is just a line!  It is 1 to 3 pixels tall.

I have no idea how I got it that way, but how do I fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a folder in my user's AppData\Roaming folder that contained the words "Cory Plotts" and "Snoop" in it.  I deleted that folder and when I restarted Snoop, it opened normally.